# How to know the line joining two points?

Tags: java, geometry

I have two points and I want to know the line which is joining them.
I don't want to draw the line.

I want to create a matrix with all the points which formed the line.

In the future, I want to solve if two points belong or not to a shape. And this is the first part.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone!! I've solved my doubts!
I have to apply the equation of the straight line!

Thanks again!

Comment: An infinite number of points make up any given line. What exactly do you mean by, "a matrix with all the points which formed the line"? And how would a matrix store them?

Comment: This is pure math. BTW, with "line" are you referncing a "SEGMENT" or any possible curved line that connects the two points?

Comment: `throw new OutOfMemoryError()` may be simpler than what you want to do, and have the same effect...

Comment: Yes I am referring a "SEGMENT". Sorry by my bad explanation.
I don't speak english very well and that it's very difficult to explain to me even in my mother language xD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

y = y1 + ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))*(x - x1)

with the usual caveats for avoiding division by 0

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for!
Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3):

Equation of a line joining two points(x1,y1) (x2,y2) is:

> (y-y1)/(y2-y1) = (x-x1)/(x2-x1)

So,any point that satisfies (x,y) in the equation will be on the line.

Answer (score 1):

you must have a function y=f(x). Take your point and calc the function. p(x1,y1) and function must y1 = f(x1).

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for!
Thanks Merin!

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite given that the line is not necessarily to be straight.

If you are talking about a straight line then it is a line f(x) = mx + c type and it is pure maths. [This article](https://www.mathsisgoodforyou.com/AS/explanations/coordinatexplain.htm) contains all the things you require..

you may need to use the following to get your "matrix"

[image]
<sub>(source: [mathsisgoodforyou.com](http://www.mathsisgoodforyou.com/images/mathsequ/coordinate95.doc))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

See the [Two point form of linear equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) if you calc the slope you can iterate from x1,y1 to x2,y2 with the required precsision to find all points between (Using point-slope form).

Answer (score 1):

In the Cartesian coordinate system, a straight line is defined by the formula `y=mx`.

Call your two points A and B.

Their coordinates are (xA, yA) and (xB, yB), respectively.

The straight line that passes through A and B can be calculated using:

```
y - yA      x - xA
------- = ---------
yB - yA    xB - xA
```